# Draw Multiple Piecharts using coreplot

Tags: ios

How to draw multiple pie charts using coreplot.Is it possible to draw these side by side?

Regards,

krishna

Comment: @krishna did you manage to draw multiple pie charts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Krishna. You can add the multiple pie charts to the same graph like this:

```
CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *) self;
CPTXYGraph      *graph;
// set up the graph parameters
...
...
hostingView.hostedGraph          = graph;  
// Pie chart 1
CPTPieChart *pieChart1           = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
// Pie Chart 2
CPTPieChart *pieChart2           = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];

// Add them to the graph
[graph addPlot:pieChart1];
[graph addPlot:pieChart2];
```